# Как сделать функцию,не пойму

Tags: php

как сделать функцию из этого,чтобы я передавал аргументы в функцию и получал результат.
Передаю аргумент `$isleader` - получаю аргумент `$isleader` только уже `String`

```
if($isleader == 0) {
    

    $isleader = "Не является лидером фракции";
       }
      if($isleader == 1) {
        $isleader = "Government";
      } 
      if($isleader == 2) {
        $isleader = "ТСР";
      } 
      if($isleader == 3) {
        $isleader = "LSPD";
      } 
      if($isleader == 4) {
        $isleader = "RCSD";
      } 
      if($isleader == 5) {
        $isleader = "SFPD";
      } 
      if($isleader == 6) {
        $isleader = "FBI";
      } 
      if($isleader == 7) {
        $isleader = "SWAT";
      } 
      if($isleader == 8) {
        $isleader = "Army LS";
      } 
      if($isleader == 9) {
        $isleader = "Army SF";
      } 
      if($isleader == 10) {
        $isleader = "LSMC";
      } 
      if($isleader == 11) {
        $isleader = "SFMC";
      } 
      if($isleader == 12) {
        $isleader = "LVMC";
      } 
      if($isleader == 13) {
        $isleader = "R-LS";
      } 
      if($isleader == 14) {
        $isleader = "R-SF";
      } 
      if($isleader == 15) {
        $isleader = "R-LV";
      } 
      if($isleader == 16) {
        $isleader = "Central Bank";
      } 
      if($isleader == 17) {
        $isleader = "Main Licensing Center";
      } 
      if($isleader == 18) {
        $isleader = "Министр Юстиции";
      } 
      if($isleader == 19) {
        $isleader = "Министр Обороны";
      } 
      if($isleader == 20) {
        $isleader = "Министр Здравоохранения";
      } 
      if($isleader == 21) {
        $isleader = "Министр Финансов и Культуры";
      } 
      if($isleader == 22) {
        $isleader = "Warlock MC";
      } 
      if($isleader == 23) {
        $isleader = "La Cosa Nostra";
      } 
      if($isleader == 24) {
        $isleader = "Yakuza";
      } 
      if($isleader == 25) {
        $isleader = "Russian Mafia";
      } 
      if($isleader == 26) {
        $isleader = "Темное Братство";
      }
     
      if($isleader == 27) {
        $isleader = "Страховая Компания";
      }
```

Comment: сделайте массив и возьмите по индексу

Comment: можно пример кода?

Comment: `$leader = ['a','b'][$leader];`

Comment: $fractions = [1 => "Government", "ТСР", "LSPD", "RCSD", "SFPD" и т.д.];
$isleader = $fractions[$isleader] ?? "Не является лидером фракции";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function f($leader) {
   $arr = [ "Government", "ТСР", "LSPD", "RCSD", "SFPD" и т.д.];
   return ($isleader < 1 or $leader > sizeof($arr)
           ?  "Не является лидером фракции" 
           : $arr[$leader - 1];
}
```

Comment: применять её просто - f($leader) ?

Comment: да, конечно. тока массив полностью заполниете